# How to use a changed value (C# / WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, service, bank

So I need to create this bank service. I have everything except I am trying to use the updated balance from a customer after a transaction such a withdraw or deposit. For example the customer starts off with $1000, and customer 1 deposits $300. The updated balance should be $1300, but once I do another transaction it goes back to the default $1000, instead of the new balance of $1300. The customers are in a list.

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode=SessionMode.Allowed)]
public interface IBankService
    {

    [OperationContract]
    string GetCustDetails(int act);

    [OperationContract]
    string WithdrawMoney(int act, double amt);

    [OperationContract]
    string DepositMoney(int act,double amt);

    [OperationContract]
    string ViewBalance(int act);


}

// Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{

    private int accountNumber; private double viewBalance,   depositMoney;
    private string customerName, customerAddress;

    public Customer(int act, string str_name, string adrs, double bal)
    {
        accountNumber = act;
        customerName = str_name;
        customerAddress = adrs;
        viewBalance = bal;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return customerName; }
        set { customerName = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Address")]
    public string CustomerAddress
    {
        get { return customerAddress; }
        set { customerAddress = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Account")]
    public int AccountNumber
    {
        get { return accountNumber; }
        set { accountNumber = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Balance", EmitDefaultValue = true)]
    public double ViewBalance           
    {
        get { return viewBalance; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0.0)
                viewBalance = 0.0;
            else
                viewBalance = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "Credit")]
    public double DepositMoney
    {
        get { return depositMoney; }
        set { depositMoney = value; }
    } 
}
```

---

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
class BankService : IBankService
{

    List<Customer> custList;

    static double balance1 = 1000;
    static double balance2 = 1000;
    static double balance3 = 1000;
    static double balance4 = 1000;
    static double balance5 = 1000;
    public BankService()
    {

        custList = new List<Customer>();
        custList.Add(new Customer(100, "Jack", "404 Bay Avenue", balance1));
        custList.Add(new Customer(200, "Jeff", "255 Wade Avenue",balance2));
        custList.Add(new Customer(300, "Lou", "984 Leslie Road", balance3));
        custList.Add(new Customer(400, "Johnson","1080 Queen Street", balance4));
        custList.Add(new Customer(500, "Alex","777 Jane Street", balance5));


    }

  public string GetCustDetails(int act)
    {
        foreach (Customer cust in custList)
        {
            if (cust.AccountNumber == act)
            {
                return string.Format("Account Number: " + cust.AccountNumber   + "\n" + 
                                     "Name:           " + cust.CustomerName    + "\n" + 
                                     "Address:        " + cust.CustomerAddress + "\n" + 
                                     "Balance:        $" + cust.ViewBalance);
            }
        } // end foreach

        return string.Format("{0}", "Customer does not exists!");
    }

    //public string DepositMoney(int act, double amt)
    //{
    //    string balance = null;
    //    foreach (Customer cust in custList)
    //    {
    //        if (cust.AccountNumber == act)
    //        {
    //            bal = bal + Dep;                  
    //        }

    //    }
    //    return balance;
    //}

    public string DepositMoney(int act, double amt)
    {
        foreach (Customer cust in custList)
        {
            if (cust.AccountNumber == act)
            {
                cust.ViewBalance = cust.ViewBalance + amt;
                return string.Format("Account Number : " + cust.AccountNumber + "\n" +
                                    "Name : " + cust.CustomerName + "\n" +
                                    "Address : " + cust.CustomerAddress + "\n" +
                                     "Balance :$ " + cust.ViewBalance);
            }
        }
        return string.Format("{0}", "Customer does not exists!");


    }


    //public double WithdrawMoney(double widraw)
    //{
    //    return bal = bal - widraw; 
    //}

    // public double ViewBalance(int act) 
    //{
    //    return bal;
    //}

    public string WithdrawMoney(int act, double amt)
    {
        foreach (Customer cust in custList)
        {
            if (cust.AccountNumber == act)
            {
                cust.ViewBalance = cust.ViewBalance - amt;
                return string.Format("Account Number : " + cust.AccountNumber + "\n" +
                                    "Name : " + cust.CustomerName + "\n" +
                                    "Address : " + cust.CustomerAddress + "\n" +
                                     "Balance :$ " + cust.ViewBalance);
            }
        }
        return string.Format("{0}", "Customer does not exists!");
    }


    public string ViewBalance(int act)
    {
        foreach (Customer cust in custList)
        {
            if (cust.AccountNumber == act)
            {
                return string.Format("Balance : $" + cust.ViewBalance);
            }
        }
        return string.Format("{0}", "Customer does not exists!");

    }

}
```

Each customer has their own account number that is already assigned.

Comment: Just several notes: 1) **never** use floating-point types, such as `float` or `double`, to store money values, use `decimal` instead; 2) never write property setters like `Customer.ViewBalance`. Consider throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` instead, if `value` is invalid; 3) almost all of your properties could be easily replaced with auto-implemented properties: `public int AccountNumber { get; set; }`; 4) Use LINQ query to find a cutomer by its acc. number: `var cust = custList.Single(c => c.AccountNumber == act);`

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you're calling the service?  Are you using the same client for the calls, or creating a new one for each call?

Comment: @Tim Yes sorry. I am using a Web Form to call the service.

Comment: Are you sure the value is changing back to the original value? Is it possible (perhaps by the way you have bound your data) that you are showing the original value despite the fact that the data has actually updated?

Comment: SIMILARLY, is it possible that you are reinstantiating a new `BankService` on each call?

Comment: @user3273287 - I think you misunderstood my question.  What I meant (and what PhatWrat asks as well), is are creating a new client to make the call to the service for every transaction?  I.e., are you doing something like `ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(); client.Method(); client.Close();` and then later on making another call to the service the same way?  Can you post some sample code from your WebForm where you make the call to the service?

Answer (score 0):

How are you consuming this service ?
I mean to say how you are creating your client (can you post some code).

Following salient points are taken into account while consuming the service

- Adding a service reference
- Creating an instance of the client
- Calling the web methods of the instance

Comment: Yes I am adding a service reference.